# Python Panda multi Line graph using time stamp

Tags: python, pandas, graph

I am trying to draw graph using python panda, So far i am able to read sqlite database. I am not able to generate graph using timestamp. I want draw multi line graph using python panda. I want Months (X axis) vs Value (Y axis) graph for different line.

Below is my output of data frame(df):

[image]

Here is my code

```
import sqlite3
from pylab import *
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime as dt


conn = sqlite3.connect('Metrics.db')
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM ABC", conn)
```

I tried using df.plot(), but it did not work.

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there are two separate objectives. One is to group your data by 'Type' and plot each line separately. To do that, you can use `df.groupby()` and then loop through groups:

```
for key, grp in df.groupby('Type'):
    plt.plot(grp['Timestamp'], grp['Value'])
```

The second question is how to format your timestamps to display the month. To do this, first convert your timestamps into datetimes, then use a formatter to print only the month name.

Here's some code that does that, combined with what we already had from the first part:

```
df['date'] = [pd.to_datetime(t, unit='s') for t in df['Timestamp']]
for key, grp in df.groupby('Type'):
    plt.plot(grp['date'], grp['Value'])
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%B'))
```

You can adjust the argument to DateFormatter if you want to change your tick label format.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I already tested with show(), it doesn't give correct output. I want Month (x axis) and Value (y axis) graph with multi line.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your problem. Does my updated answer give what you're looking for?

Comment: Its almost correct. Instead of time stamp on x axis, i want month name from time stamp.

Comment: One way is just to add the month as another column on your DataFrame, and then plot that column instead of Timestamp.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show how to format the tick labels to just the month name. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: thanks answer. How do i pass multiple sql statement in data frame. Here  df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM ABC", conn)

Comment: It seems like that's a separate question from your original one and deserves its own topic thread. Please post it as a brand new question on the site so that it gets top-level visibility, and that way more people can help answer it. Hopefully I've helped you with the original question!

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If so, please consider marking it as accepted. If not, please let us know where it isn't working for you. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for help. it works for me. i customized bit as per my requirement.

Comment: Do you have any idea about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29283618/python-panda-time-series-re-sampling

Comment: What does the `for key, grp in' bit do please?

Comment: @Laura Answering in 3 comments. Hard to know which part you don't know so forgive me for starting too basic! The "for loop" is a way of iterating through a collection of items and exists in most programming languages. As we "iterate" through the loop, the variable name we specify progressively takes on the values of the items the collection. (See here for more on Python's for loop: https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop.)

Comment: Sometimes, as in the above case, the items we're looping through are themselves "tuples" containing multiple values. In this case, using `for var in` would loop such that `var` takes on values that are tuples that look like `('x', 'y')`. In these cases, we are allowed to provide multiple variable names directly in the for loop, thus assigning each member of the tuple to each of the variable names directly (rather than assigning the whole tuple to one variable name). In the above case, `key` and `grp` are such arbitrary variable names.

Comment: Sorry if this is dense – good luck. The above is basically completely independent from pandas groupby. So perhaps worth learning thetwo concepts separately. The only connection is that pandas groupby objects can be iterated through as tuples. For more on pandas groupby, see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Answer (score 0):

The following will convert the data frame index into Pandas timestamps:

```
import datetime

df.index = [pd.Timestamp(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts)) for ts in df.Timestamp]
```