# Python Panda TIme series re sampling

Tags: python, time-series, resampling

I am writing scripts in panda but i could not able to extract correct output that i want. here it is problem:

i can read this data from CSV file. Here you can find table structure

http://postimg.org/image/ie0od7ejr/

I want this output from above table data

```
Month     Demo1 Demo 2
June 2013 3     1    
July 2013 2     2
```

in Demo1 and Demo2 column i want to count regular entry and entry which starts with u. for June there are total 3 regular entry while 1 entry starts with u.

so far i have written this code.

```
   import sqlite3
   from pylab import *       
   import numpy as np
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   import matplotlib.dates as mdates
   import datetime as dt

   conn = sqlite3.connect('Demo2.sqlite')
   df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM Data", conn)
   df['DateTime'] = df['DATE'].apply(lambda x: dt.date.fromtimestamp(x))

   df1 = df.set_index('DateTime', drop=False)
```

Thanks advace for help. End result would be bar graph. I can draw graph from output that i mention above.

Comment: Please post raw input data and code you've tried

Answer (score 0):

For `resample`, you can define two aggregation functions like this:

```
def countU(x):
    return sum(i[0] == 'u' for i in x)

def countNotU(x):
    return sum(i[0] != 'u' for i in x)

print df.resample('M', how=[countU, countNotU])
```

Alternatively, consider `groupby`.

Comment: i don't get your answer

Comment: @user3930865 It's really hard to help you any further unless you include some your raw input data or more code.

Comment: What happens when you try what I gave you? Does it produce the wrong result? Does it cause an error? Please provide specific feedback, otherwise there's no way for me to know how to revise my previous answer.

Comment: what is x in your answer ?

Comment: I have defined two aggregation functions. Then I call them in `resample`. When you make the call to `resample`, the columns of your dataframe get passed to the aggregator as `x`, and then the functions return how many of the column's elements start or do not start with 'u'.