# Plot bar graph using multiple groupby count in panda

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am trying to plot bar graph using pandas. DataTime is index column which I get from timestamp. Here is table structure:

[image: table structure]

So far i have written this:

```
import sqlite3
from pylab import *
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime as dt

conn = sqlite3.connect('DEMO2.sqlite')
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM Data", conn)
df['DateTime'] = df['DATE'].apply(lambda x: dt.date.fromtimestamp(x))

df1 = df.set_index('DateTime', drop=False)     

grouped= df1['DateTime'].groupby(lambda x: x.month)    
#df1.groupby([df1.index.month, 'DateTime']).count()    
grouped.count()
```

I want output like this:

[image: date vs. X and Y]

June has total 4 entry and one entry starts with u. so X has 4 y has 1. Same for July.

Also i want to plot bar graph (X and Y entries) using output. I want  MONTH vs Values bar graph

Comment: This is a near-exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29283618/python-panda-time-series-re-sampling/.

Comment: Please write your questions so they make sense without reference to links to external sites. Questions on SO should be helpful to future readers, and if those links die your question will be very hard to understand. Also, please do not post links to images of text  (or embed direct images of text) -  post the text itself, perhaps in a Quote block, or in a Code block if you need to preserve formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would created the DataFrame with a dict:

```
result = pd.DataFrame({'X': g.count(),
                       'Y': g.apply(lambda x: x.str.startswith('u').sum())})
```

Now you can use the plot method to plot months vs values.

```
result.plot()
```

---

Note: you can create grouped more efficiently:

```
grouped = df1['DateTime'].groupby(df1['DateTime'].dt.to_period('M'))

grouped = df1['DateTime'].groupby(df1['DateTime'].dt.month)  # if you want Jan-2015 == Jan-2014
```

Comment: I am getting an error when i use your groupby code. This is error "'Series' object has no attribute 'dt'". This is sample data on my df['DateTime'] => 2013-06-25

Comment: @user3930865 you need to ensure your Series is of datetime64 type, rather than - say - strings... e.g. using df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime']). Also ensure you're using a fairly recent version of pandas >= 0.15.

Comment: I am using panda version # 0.14.1. my df['DateTime'].dtype is object. It should be  datetime64 as per your last comment. I tried to convert it but i could not solve the problem.  I am using anaconda with 2.7 python version

Comment: I use pf['DateTime'] = pf['DATE'].apply(lambda x: dt.date.fromtimestamp(x))              to convert timestamp to date. Also to groupby i use this df1['DateTime'].groupby(lambda x: x.month). In my final output i want Month-Year on x axis.

Comment: @user3930865 use `pd.to_datetime` rather than apply. If you use the apply it may not create a Datetime column. I think you may have to update to 0.15.X for the dt accessor. If you want month-year then use the `to_period` part of the answer above?

Comment: result.plot() does not short the month and year together. it short by only month, thats why i get plot for Jan 2014 Jan 2015 together.

Comment: how to short result data frame

Comment: @user3930865 you should ask that as a new question :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29777828/python-panda-dataframe-sorting-with-month-year