# Python Panda dataframe sorting with month - year

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, graph

I am a python and pandas beginner and I'm having trouble sorting a data frame after a groupby operation. I can get sorted data after groupby and count but when I put all the data together in another data frame, I dont get sorted data.

Here is my attempt

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('Demo.sqlite')

df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM Table where Column  LIKE 'x.%'", conn)
pf = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM Table", conn)

df['DateTime'] = df['DATE'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(x).strftime('%b %Y'))
pf['DateTime'] = pf['DATE'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(x).strftime('%b %Y'))

df1 = df.set_index('DateTime', drop=False)
pf1 = pf.set_index('DateTime', drop=False)

df1 = df1.sort(['DateTime'])
pf1 = pf1.sort(['DateTime'])

R1= df1['DateTime'].groupby(lambda x: x)
R2= pf1['DateTime'].groupby(lambda x: x)
TT= TotalBuild.count() - PrivateBuild.count()

result = pd.DataFrame({'R1': R1.count(),
                       'TT': TT,
                       'R2': R2.count()
                       })
```

Here is output of result data frame.

[Check the output of Result data frame here](http://postimg.org/image/x93lxihyd/)

I want to sort dataframe by month-year. currently data frame is sorted by month, that's why all the data for January is displaying together. once data is sorted i want to draw bar graphs.

Comment: You can upload images to stackoverflow and embed them in your question as well - see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post. No need to upload them to questionable sites.

Comment: Thank You for letting me know. I did not have enough reputation, so i include link. Once i have good reputations. I will include image in this question. Most importatntly if you know answer than post the solution.

Comment: Have you tried splitting the DateTime column into two columns, month and year? Then you can sort by year, then by month.

Comment: I tried to split month and year but it dosn't work. If you have solution than can you please post ?

Answer (score 3):

One simple way is to just convert the index to date, sort and then convert back to month-year.

```
result.index = pd.to_datetime(result.index)
result.sort_index(inplace=True)
result.index = monthly_transpose.index.strftime('%B-%Y')
```

When converting to date, pandas converts the month-year to the first date of each month nad hence the sorting is made possible. Hope it helps.