# Re-order DataFrame based on month (not alphabet)

Tags: python

For a DataFrame, let's call it weather1:

```
        Temp
Month   
Apr     61
Jan     32
Jul     69
Oct     43
```

I would like to sort Month based on the actual calendar month order, and not alphabetically.

I can do the following:

```
ordered= ['Jan','Apr','Jul','Oct']
df.reindex(ordered)
```

However I am looking for a more dynamic way to do this, perhaps using "date part" functions.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39078261/4662041

Comment: @Sheshnath I don't seem to be able to figure out how to use that example to apply to mine, with only having %b from date in the index. Also I get an error 'Index' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having formatted your data in order to make a MCVE:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'smonth': ['Apr', 'Jan', 'Jul', 'Oct']
   ,'temp': [61, 32, 69, 43]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

We have the following DataFrame:

```
  smonth  temp
0    Apr    61
1    Jan    32
2    Jul    69
3    Oct    43
```

Now we convert your String Month (using `%b` formatter, see [list](http://strftime.org/)) column into a Date, then into an Index and we finally extract Month field:

```
df['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.to_datetime(df['smonth'], format='%b')).month
```

Then reindex and sort:

```
df = df.set_index('month').sort_index()
```

It is done:

```
      smonth  temp
month             
1        Jan    32
4        Apr    61
7        Jul    69
10       Oct    43
```

**Update**

If I explicitly reproduce your input, using:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    data['temp']
   ,index=pd.Index(data['smonth'], name='Month')
   ,columns=['Temp']
)
```

Then it reduces to:

```
df2.index = pd.to_datetime(df2.index, format='%b').month
df2.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

And returns:

```
       Temp
Month      
1        32
4        61
7        69
10       43
```