# Ordering months on x-axis in pandas bar chart

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to order my bar chart from Jan-Dec instead of highest count of lowest, I'm sure there is an easy fix but I cannot find it. Currently, my graph is ordering itself on the values and not the months on the x-axis.
The first line of code I added a month column. The second I found the counts of each month. The third I plot in bar chart.

```
df1['Month Added'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df1['Date Added']).month_name()
df_month = df1['Month Added'].value_counts()
df_month.plot(kind='bar')
```

Output is [image]

I tried the following but no luck.

```
df_month.Month.value_counts().loc[['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']].plot(kind='bar')
```

Comment: I think this answer may be useful: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47523483/re-order-dataframe-based-on-month-not-alphabet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pandas.Series.sort_index` with `key` and `pandas.to_datetime`:

```
df_month = df_month.sort_index(key=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format="%B"))
print(df_month)
```

Output:

```
January      25
February     21
March        14
April         5
May          30
June         16
July          8
August       30
September     6
October       9
November     36
December     24
dtype: int64
```

Then plot:

```
df_month.plot(kind="bar")
```

Output:

[image]